# Versioning in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have searched for differences between major and minor version. But i am not able to find answers apart from version numbers. Can anyone tell me some other differences for these two..???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With major versions enabled, a new version of your document is created every time the document is modified. All users of your document library can see each new version. You can access previous versions with the Version History item action.

With major and minor versions enabled, minor versions are created with each edit and major versions are created only when you choose to publish one. The Draft Item Security setting comes into play to determine who can see the new versions:

- "Any user who can read" = Any user who can access the library can read the major and minor versions. I personally don't use this setting since it behaves the same as just using just major versions, apart from the numbering.
- "Only users who can edit" = Users with Read can only see major (x.0) versions; users with Contribute or above can see major and minor versions. This is useful if you want only "final" versions of a document to be available to users with Read. It allows you to edit documents internally without worrying who can see the interim (minor) versions. When you have a final version ready--which may involve several draft versions--you publish a major version. If a user with Read accesses the document when editing is in progress, they will only see the last published major version; they will know nothing about the minor versions.

With either major or major/minor versions, take some time to consider how many versions you want to keep. The SharePoint database stores a copy of the document for every major and minor version created, and new versions are created whether you edit the actual document or just the document properties/metadata. If you have a 10MB document with 100 edits over the course of a year, that single document takes up ~1GB in the database. You may want to limit the number of major versions to something reasonable for your audit requirements and the number of draft versions to 1, which deletes all draft versions when a major version is published.

Comment: I know he tagged SP2010 but the title mentions 2013. With shredded storage, those 100 edits will consume far less than 1GB thanks to SharePoint only storing the deltas for each version.

Another important point about draft item security - If version "1.0" was never published, nobody but the user (and site collection admins) will be able to actually see the document in the library until that initial publish. It can get very confusing

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the differences versioning and list settings can have between pages, documents and list items -- and how content approval can also affect visibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer mr.John Saunders. This gave me a clear idea about versions.